# cellForRowAtIndexPath inserting in array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm getting a weird issue. I have a custom UITableViewCell and each cell has a UIButton and UITextField. When the button is clicked, it changes the textfield value to some constant.

Now in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method I have this:

```
    folderTitleTextView.tag=indexPath.row;
    [arrayOfTextFields insertObject:folderTitleTextView atIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"indexpath.row:%i", indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"text fields count %i", [arrayOfTextFields count]);
```

So if I have two cells, then every time I reload the table, it adds two more objects to the arrayofTextFields, even though it should replace the existing ones. So if I have two cells and I reload the table 3 times, then for some reason arrayOfTextFields count is 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `folderTitleTextView.tag=indexPath.row;` is not a good idea because everything starts with a tag of `0`, so when accessing views with `viewWithTag:0` or when setting up the row `0`, you will get weird results.

I would suggest also checking the number of items in `arrayOfTextFields` and use `[arrayOfTextFields replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:folderTitleTextView];` or `[arrayOfTextFields insertObject:folderTitleTextView atIndex:indexPath.row];` depending on the current count for `arrayOfTextFields`

Try this:

```
folderTitleTextView.tag = (indexPath.row + 100);
if ([arrayOfTextFields count] <= indexPath.row) {
    [arrayOfTextFields insertObject:folderTitleTextView atIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    [arrayOfTextFields replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:folderTitleTextView];
}
NSLog(@"indexpath.row:%i", indexPath.row);
NSLog(@"text fields count %i", [arrayOfTextFields count]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to fix the problem with this: `if(indexPath.row<[arrayOfTextFields count])
        [arrayOfTextFields replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:folderTitleTextView];
    else
        [arrayOfTextFields addObject:folderTitleTextView]; `

Answer (score 1):

The question is what are you trying to do?

Right now you add the textView to an array each time a cell is displayed.

If you have 1 cell you have 1 textView in the array because `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` was called 1 time.
If you add another cell so you have 2 total cell cellForRowAtIndexPath will be called another 2 times and it will add 2 textViews to the array that already has one -> 3
If you add another cell cellForRowAtIndexPath adds 3 more textViews to the 3 that are already there -> 6

So much for the explanation of your results.

---

My suggestion is to get rid of that array and get rid of the tag, most likely those are not needed at all.

you can access the cell with something like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIView *contentView = [sender superview];
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[contentView superview];
    // you should assign a tag to the textField of your cell. Use the same tag for each textView in all cells. 
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:42];
    textField.text = @"Foo";
}
```

Comment: Each custom cell has a UITextField which holds the cells title, and a button that enabled the text field for editing and assigns it as the first responder. So what I'm trying to do is make it so that when the button is pressed, it accesses a certain text view from the array and edits it. However, I need to set their tags so I can access the right text view. If I have 5 cells, then there are 5 buttons, and I don't set their tags, then when I press it, it won't know which textfield to edit.

Comment: did you see the second part that I have added? Probably you don't need tags and you don't need arrays where you store textViews.

Comment: Hmm that's a good idea, but my custom cell doesn't have its own class and is owned by the same class that owns the table. So I couldnt access a cell's folderTitleTextView like that..or could I?

Comment: I made another edit, I would suggest to assign a tag to the textView.  And the same tag for the textViews in all of your cells.